# How to add git commits and tags for the history of a project

Tags: git, tags, push, commit, history

I forgot to add commits and tags that were supposed to be done for my project. Although, there were only minor changes (which I remember and can make them now), I want to commit and create a git tag. Is it possible to pull down a commit and add a git tag to it and push it?

It is just so messy and I want to fix it now before moving forward. Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tag is easy; tags are not part of commits, they just reference commits, so you can add a tag that points to anything at any time. It's unclear what you mean about adding a commit. Do you want to amend an existing commit, or just commit more code? You'll need to give more detail about your exact situation.

Comment: Yes, I need to edit some files and commit and then tag it. And there have been like 10 code commits on top of it now.. So if commits are identified as  - 1, 2, 3(is where I want to commit some code), 4, 5, 6, 7 (want to commit code and tag), 8, 9, 10* (want to commit code and tag).. And neither of the code commits will alter/disrupt the existing code base (am 100% sure about it).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an interactive rebase, but be aware of the risks of rewriting history that you have already shared.

First, start the rebase with `git rebase -i <commit2>`. This will open an editor window that looks something like this:

```
pick 8e1729c <msg3>
pick 5f4f4b1 <msg4>
pick d0936bb <msg5>
pick 652eb5c <msg6>
pick ceebbb7 <msg7>
pick d42a432 <msg8>
pick e203251 <msg9>
pick 7701829 <msg10>
```

You'll edit the first column in this file like this:

```
edit 8e1729c <msg3>
pick 5f4f4b1 <msg4>
pick d0936bb <msg5>
pick 652eb5c <msg6>
pick ceebbb7 <msg7>
pick d42a432 <msg8>
pick e203251 <msg9>
pick 7701829 <msg10>
```

Save the file and quit. Git will start the rebase by reapplying the commits shown, but stopping after the first one so that you can make changes or simply add a commit before continuing. If you want to amend the original 3rd commit, just make your changes now and continue with

```
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

If you want to modify the original 3rd commit, "undo" it with

```
git reset HEAD^
```

then make any changes you want before continuing with

```
# stage all your changes
git commit
git rebase --continue
```

Once the rebase it complete, you can the make your final changes to the last commit by making your edits, and amending commit 10 with

```
# stage changes
git commit --amend
```

Once your commits are in order, use `git log` to find the new SHA for the two commits you want to tag (the rebase and `--amend` will have changed them!), and simply run

```
git tag <commit3hash> <tagname>
git tag <commit10hash> <tagname>
```

and push everything to your remote

```
git push -f   # You need to force it, since you've rewritten history
git push --tags
```

Comment: Great..thanks for the detailed answer. I will try it carefully and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to rewriting history, you could make some temporary branches at the point where the commits should have been done and then merge them back into master.

I think it's a bit less disruptive for other users (when pulling for instance) of the repository if things got published, while still attaching the commits to its intended parent.

Do the first commit:

```
$ git checkout -b first-commit 3
$ [do stuff]
$ git add [stuff]
$ git commit
```

Then do the second commit:

```
$ git checkout -b second-commit 7
$ [do stuff]
$ git add [stuff]
$ git commit
```

And the first tag:

```
$ git tag first-tag
```

Then merge the branches:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge first-commit
$ git merge second-commit
```

And tag it:

```
$ git tag second-tag
```

Get rid of the branches:

```
$ git branch -d first-commit
$ git branch -d second-commit
```

Finally push:

```
$ git push
$ git push --tags
```

The history will look something like this:

```
                                                    second-tag
                                                         |
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- 6 -- 7 -- 8 -- 9 -- 10 -- 11 -- 12
           \                   \                  /      /
            3' -----------------\----------------+      /
                                 7'--------------------+
                                 |
                             first-tag
```